# Using JSON to define Handlebars JS partials: define the name of the partial in the JSON and have Handlebars JS render that partial

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

We are using a config.json to setup a Handlebars-based layout to generate emails from templates. This json config includes the partials name and the content (image, headline and description) for that partial.

The **/partials/..** are called:

- primary.html
- secondary.html

Here is an example of the **/data/config.json** - you can see the "modules" node contains the partials and their content:

```
{
    "subject": "my email subject",
    "pretext": "this is the pretext text",
    "modules": {
        "primary":{
            "image": {
                "src": "primary-hero.jpg",
                "alt": "This is the primary image"
            },
            "headline": "Primary Headline",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nulla ipsam ratione rem incidunt quasi quos, possimus cumque neque corporis, dignissimos deserunt perspiciatis totam. Totam itaque distinctio deserunt fugiat nostrum."
            },
        "secondary":{
            "image": {
                "src": "secondary-hero.jpg",
                "alt": "This is the secondary hero image"
            },
            "headline": "Secondary Headline",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nulla ipsam ratione rem incidunt quasi quos, possimus cumque neque corporis, dignissimos deserunt perspiciatis totam. Totam itaque distinctio deserunt fugiat nostrum."
            },
    }
}
```

I currently have a handlebars loop in **/pages/index.html** that works, but uses a comparison helper. Clearly this approach has issues given that it forces an arbitrary rendering order and also fails when a partial is repeated in the json:

```
{{#each config.modules}}
  {{#ifEqual @key "primary"}}
    {{> primary}}
  {{/ifEqual}}
  {{#ifEqual @key "secondary"}}
    {{> secondary}}
  {{/ifEqual}}
{{/each}}
```

More ideally, the loop would look like this:

```
{{#each config.modules}}
  {{ > @key }}
{{/each}}
```

That fails, of course:

```
Panini: rendering error ocurred.
 { [Error: The partial @key could not be found]
  description: undefined,
  fileName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined,
  message: 'The partial @key could not be found',
  name: 'Error',
  number: undefined }
```

Is there any way to do accomplish this — to pass a partial name via json?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Handlebars, so there might be a better way, but I came up with this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderPartial', (key) => key);
```

To use:

```
{{#each config.modules}}
  {{> (renderPartial @key) }}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Not a bad thought. However, this just results in the @ key value being the output and Handelbars not actually rendering the partial. It's currently showing the following text inside my template: primary certificate

Comment: @christian_pn see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5b69e35add4f5b5f121d344e2986769d) for a standalone example. Perhaps I misunderstood what you want to achieve? (`handlebars@4.0.5`)

Answer (score 0):

I've figure it out based on this thread: https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/issues/121

> "Subexpressions do not resolve variables so [the name] must be a function."

I created a helper that simply returns a string:

**getPartial**

```
module.exports = function(name) {
    return name;
};
```

In the Handlebars render loop:

```
{{#each config.modules}}
  {{> (getPartial @key) }}
{{/each}}
```

It now renders without error. However, it still seems to have an issue when a partial is repeated in the JSON, it only renders one, single instance of that partial.

So, while "secondary" is included twice in the JSON, it only renders the partial once:

```
{
    "subject": "my email subject",
    "pretext": "this is the pretext text",
    "modules": {
        "primary":{
            "image": {
                "src": "primary-hero.jpg",
                "alt": "This is the primary image"
            },
            "headline": "Primary Headline",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nulla ipsam ratione rem incidunt quasi quos, possimus cumque neque corporis, dignissimos deserunt perspiciatis totam. Totam itaque distinctio deserunt fugiat nostrum."
            },
        "secondary":{
            "image": {
                "src": "secondary-hero.jpg",
                "alt": "This is the secondary hero image"
            },
            "headline": "Secondary Headline",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nulla ipsam ratione rem incidunt quasi quos, possimus cumque neque corporis, dignissimos deserunt perspiciatis totam. Totam itaque distinctio deserunt fugiat nostrum."
            },
        "secondary":{
            "image": {
                "src": "secondary-hero.jpg",
                "alt": "This is the secondary hero image"
            },
            "headline": "Secondary Headline",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nulla ipsam ratione rem incidunt quasi quos, possimus cumque neque corporis, dignissimos deserunt perspiciatis totam. Totam itaque distinctio deserunt fugiat nostrum."
            },
    }
}
```

This must be directly related to the fact that the render list is in a loop and the @key must be unique? If I list the partials directly, it will render "secondary" twice as expected:

```
{{> primary}}
{{> secondary}}
{{> secondary}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what my answer does as well (except it looks like you forgot to mention that you're using `express-handlebars` and not the plain `handlebars` module). Also, you can't have an object that has the same key twice, when you add a key to an object that already exists it'll just overwrite the previous one.